# rails n:m how to have rails associations when the db table names are different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, associations, has-many, tablename

I have a project which does not follow the rails nameing conventions, because it is not possible for a special case.

Scenario:
I have a model called Foo, and the database table for this model called example_foos.
I have a model called Bar, and the database table for this model called example_bars.

I want to create a n:m association between these two models with a model FooBar. Database table name for this model is ExampleFooExampleBars.

Now my question..how can I specify the has_many throught association in the models?
If I do it like normal, I get errors because the model and table names are different..

Comment: Please show your current code that gets the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associations are referring to the **class names**, so:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'example_foos'
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'example_bars'
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model and table has different name you can

```
class Foo <ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "example_foos"
end
```

rest of association as per rails convention way